# projecting multiple columns in ADX with wild cards

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

If I have too many columns and a bunch of them start with similar strings , is there a way in Kusto to select them based on this pattern , such as using wild cards etc ?

e.g. Assuming we have some of the columns like `datafield1, datafield2 ...` , something like the following would be helpful

```
mytable | project datafield*
```

I know that this is not syntactically valid , so is there any workaround for achieving this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[project-keep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/project-keep-operator) does exactly what you want:

```
mytable | project-keep datafield*
```